# Networkx shortest_path does not giving a shortest path

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

Trying to get a closest path from house points to nearest parks. Use three geojson files to get coordinates and put them into `nx.Graph()`. I didn't set weight or any other graph parameter except node type which are 'road', 'house' and 'park'.

After graph preparation I loop all house nodes, find shortest paths to all parks and then take the path which has shortest length to get the closest park to a house.

But as I have seen in QGIS some paths are definitely not the shortests ones. I checked for missing nodes but no mistakes there. I think this is because `nx` tries to take as less edges as possible and this is way is not going on curve lines despite the fact that it's much closer.

[image]

As you can see here the green line is a shortes path given by `nx.shortest_path()`, but obviously there should be another way through a curve line which explodes to many edges.

What should be done here to build a path the right way?

Comment: First question is which kind of street graph you used, i.e. what is a node in your graph? is it a junction or is it a street? I guess your nodes are junctions and the edges are streets. Then you need to put as weights in the shortest path calculation the length of the street segment. This should give you the desired results. As you stated currently shortest path does not minimise the distance but the number of junctions.

Comment: @Sparky05 Right, I used vertices of line as nodes and pairs of node numbers as tuples to make edges. Is that would be okay if weight will be a length of line? Just want to understand logic of using weights.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in your model a node is a line, which means it is a street? If yes, then it's more difficult to set weights to the edges. Spontaneously setting the sum of the streets as length for the edges may work, but I have some doubts because all "inner lines" would be counted twice and the first and last only once. Easier would be to use the other graph, where a line is an edge.

Comment: @Sparky05 I have already fixed that using weights as you recommended. Took it from every coordinate pair, calculated line length. As for model I use line as edges and vertices as nodes.

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question and update, which challenge you currently face? With (the right) weights on the edges, a usual call of `nx.shortest_path` should do the job ;) You may also want to look at [`osmnx`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), if you're working with OpenStreetMap data

Comment: @Sparky05 well the problem is solved by now with your advice so I can actually close it... But if you want a rate points here, you can make an answer and I put a green tick. Anyway thanks for your help with weights! As for OSM, I try use it in less precise job because its road data is quite dirty sometimes